# Load data from server after event on front end

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

At the moment, I try to connect my ember.js application with my webserver. The web application has a datepicker. After a date was selected I like my model to "reload". With reload I mean asking my webserver for the new data containing the specific date.

Below you see my route contacting the server for the required information.

```
App.PicturesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return $.getJSON('http://api.<server>.com/pictures?date=' + params.date).then(function(data) {
            return data.pictures.map(function(picture) {
                picture.body = picture.content;
                return event;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

In the case that I write the date manually in the string everything works fine and I receive data. Now, I have the problem that I don't figure out how to do it dynamically. How should I create the best connection between UI and model. Of course I can implement an action in my controller but how should this controller call/reload the model?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `date` is part of your URL you should just use `transitionTo` or `transitionToRoute`.  You probably have a route set up that allows you to match URLs that look something like `/pictures/2013-10-09`.  Things get a little funky since `2013-10-09` isn't really an object id.  Usually with `transitionToRoute` Ember expects that you'll pass in a live model that represents the content you're transitioning to.  This would be the same object that Ember would look up by executing the `model` hook if the route is hit directly (without `link-to` or `transitionTo`).  Since the date is really a query param and not an id you can use the `setupController` method to get around the funkiness.

So, your route might look something like this (this is simplified, you'll want to use the appropriate AJAX calls, of course) :

```
App.PicturesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params){
    console.log('calling model for PicturesRoute');
    return { date : params.date }; // return a fake model
  },
  setupController : function(controller, model){
    // Make sure not to call super since we don't want to set
    // a single object instead of an array
    // this._super(controller,model); <-- do not use!
    console.log('calling setupController for PicturesRoute');
    // Instead set the `date` property directly
    controller.set('date',model.date);
    // Then find/build an array and set it as the model
    var pictures = [
      {name : "Pic 1 - " + model.date},
      {name : "Pic 2 - " + model.date}
    ];
    controller.set('model',pictures);
    console.log(model);
  }
});
```

Then within the app when you detect a change from the date picker you'd call something like this :

```
var dateFromPicker = ... // however you get a hold of the date string from the picker
var fakeModel = { date : dateFromPicker };
this.transitionTo('pictures',fakeModel);
```

Here's a JSBin showing a very simplified version of this idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1396/edit

I hope that makes sense.